# Why is ggplot2 not plotting my scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

This is a really silly question: I have used ggplot2 many times before but this time it is not plotting the scale on my y axis, but it is also not giving me any error msg...

This is what I have in case someone can figure it out what is going wrong:

```
    graph.1 <- subset(school.year, year > 1930 & year < 1940)
ggplot(graph.1, aes(x=year, y=school.y)) + geom_line() +
  geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=qtr), hjust=1.5) +
  xlab("Year of birth") +
  ylab("Years of completed education") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(15.2, 17, 0.2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1930, 1940, 2)) +
  # To remove the gray background:
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
       panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
       panel.border = element_blank(),
       panel.background = element_blank())
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, as lame as this is I just figured it out... The problem was with my "scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(15.2, 17, 0.2))", I have values that are out of that limit and as soon as I fixed it, it worked. I am not sure if should just delete this post or if this silly question can be of any help for someone. Feel free to delete it if you want to.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, as soon as you're allowed to (there may be a minimum time)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was with your subsetting the data frame. When you subset `year>1930`, scale_x does not get 1930. Here is a **reproducible example data** for your problem that does not show the tick marks as expected when you run your code.

```
set.seed(3487)
y <- seq(15, 17, by=.1)
x = sample(1930:1940, size=length(y), replace=T)
z = sample(1:4, size=length(y), replace=T)
school.year <- data.frame(year =x, school.y=y, qtr=z)
```

And when you subset including year 1930, the tick labels work nicely

```
graph.1 <- subset(school.year, year >= 1930 & year <= 1940)
```